# Is it possible to send two dataframes to my html (flask)?

Tags: python, html, flask

So my html page receives a pandas dataframe.

```
return render_template('example.html', tables=[data_frame.to_html(classes='data')], titles=dataframe.columns.values)
```

and my html page displays it:

```
{% for table in tables %}
            {{titles[loop.index]}}
            {{ table|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

What I want to do is display two separate dataframes in my html page. How can I do this?

For example: 
If I have dataframes df1 and df2,

in the html page I want to display them after some text.

```
show df1

<h2> some text </h2>

show df2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `render_template` accepts dictionaries, you can pass a Dict object named context or whatever to the "render_template" function with "table" and "title" keys.
And then in your Jinja you can access these keys by `context.table` and `context.title`.

Example:

```
def my_function(request):
    ...
    get your dataframe
    ...
    context = {"tables":[data_frame.to_html(classes='data')],
               "titles" : dataframe.columns.values,
              }

    return render_template('template.html', context=context)
```

Comment: can you please give an example? I'm learning still so I'd appreciate it alot!

Comment: Yes, I understood! Thankyou so much!

Comment: Would it be possible to get an answer on how to call these in jinja2? I have the following syntax and am getting an error:

{% for table in dataframes.tables %}
  {{titles[0][loop.index]}}
  {{ table[0]|safe }}
{% endfor %}

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily in **render_template**

Your code can be changed like this:

```
return render_template('example.html',tables= [data_frame1.to_html(classes='data'),data_frame2.to_html(classes='data')], 
titles=['na','FirstTable','SecondTable'])
```

As you can see , you can add more than one dataframe in tables.

Now in Jinja, you can simply loop through each table(dataframe) and display

```
{% for table in tables %}
{{ titles[loop.index] }}
{{ table|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

Refer the below image for your reference:

[image: Sample image for your reference]

Comment: Is it possible to only display one of these tables? I would like to show them in different locations on the page EDIT: I figured it out, it's just {{tables[index]}}